# % syntax in Python

Tags: python, syntax

I was working on a project in which I had to write

```
%matplotlib inline
```

at the beginning to solve a problem.

But I'm wondering what does this "%" stands for: is it an operator ? Has it a name so I could do some researches about it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not looking at standard Python code.

You are almost certainly using an [IPython interactive session](http://ipython.org/), and it uses `%` as a prefix to recognize special commands, called *magic functions*. Type `%quickref` to get a quick reference. From that reference:

> `%magic`           : Information about IPython's 'magic' `%` functions.
>
> Magic functions are prefixed by `%` or `%%`, and typically take their arguments
>   without parentheses, quotes or even commas for convenience.  Line magics take a
>   single `%` and cell magics are prefixed with two `%%`.

If you then type in `%magic` you'll find the reference documentation for available magic functions, including:

> `%matplotlib`:
>
> ```
>  %matplotlib [gui]
> ```
>
> Set up matplotlib to work interactively.
>
> This function lets you activate matplotlib interactive support
>       at any point during an IPython session. It does not import anything
>       into the interactive namespace.